# IE 7/8/9 , £ displayed as "?" .. Ajax + POST + Jquery and JSON .. what can fix IE character encoding Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, iso-8859-15

I have a string like "£300 ON 110406" which I'm displaying to User.
following is the Ajax which is getting fired to the spring controller which returns the data from DB:-

DB values are getting pushed through a separate Product , so can't change anything there.

`$.ajax({
    header:{
    Accept:"*/*",
    "Mime-Type":"application/x-javascript;charset=iso-8859-15"
                },
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType:'json',
    url: ctx + "/url.htm",
    data: str,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    if(jqXHR && jqXHR.overrideMimeType) {
        jqXHR.overrideMimeType('application/x-javascript;charset=iso-8859-15'); 
    }
},`

previously above string was not coming fine on FIreFox and Chrome as well but after i added "beforeSend" method , now they are coming fine.

but IE still gives BOX characters.

Above Ajax code I have modified after googling most of the questions available for similar issue.

My page says below :-

`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15"
    pageEncoding="iso-8859-15"%>
    <% request.setCharacterEncoding("iso-8859-15"); %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">`

On my other page , I'm displaying same value but using Scriptlet so there no issues.

signature of my spring controller method:-
If i add produces to this method , i get "cannot find presentation in browser console"

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private @ResponseBody
    String getFilteredData(`

Jquery version is 1.11

I have been trying this in IE but it just don't work.. below is the screen shot from IE browser to show Accept and content-type.

If i change content type in Ajax then it does send data to the controller.

[image]

can you please let me know , how this can be resolved.

Comment: Why the use of the specific charset ISO-8859-15?  Normally UTF-8 has the characters compatibility for most characters.

Comment: Yes , it does but £ is not getting supported. So unless i push mime type to be iso-8859-15 through beforesend method , it shows ? in all browsers. And in IE , even after doing that its boxes characters..

Comment: In that case you probably have stored the data in the database as UTF-8.  That is trickier to convert to UTF-8.  Check to be sure that the overrideMimeType is called in IE with a breakpoint.  It doesn't seem to be the case by the looks of it.

Comment: Yes , i believe external product is stroing in iso-8859-15 , 
I placed a break point in IE java script and it executes overrideMimeType but does not make any effect ..
as i read from many articles , IE does not support overrideMimeType

Comment: Check to see if you have access to the underlying xmlhttprequest object, if so you can `setRequestHeader('Content-Type','YOUR CONTENT TYPE');`

Comment: i setted the content type :-

beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-javascript;charset=iso-8859-15');

but no help , still box characters